# GridView elements horizontal spacing not working at all

Tags: android-layout, gridview, imageview, android

So here's how my grid view looks like:
[a http://imageshack.com/a/img41/7857/roir.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img41/7857/roir.png)
I use some online JSON parsing and get the image thumbnail links and then pass it on as an array to the custom adapter and it sets images for which I again use some 3rd party library etc. But the 3rd party library is just used to set the image to the imageview. That's it.

So I have a main FragmentActivity. It has 2 fragments inside of it. The textbox u see there is inside one fragment(search fragment) and on top of it, the gridview is held by the second fragment. (results fragment)

Code for the results fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    tools:context="com.example.wikipicsearch.MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for the layout that I pass onto the custom Adapter:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I have no clue why on earth is there no horizontal spacing between each of that linear layout. I tried using `android:layout_marginLeft` etc etc... nothing works at all! I made the fragment holding the gridview look grey so that the each element in the grid will leave some spacing and it should look good. Please help me out with this. TIA!

Comment: Did you tried to set android:horizontalSpacing="5dp" in your GridView's xml?

Comment: try this..,add horizonatl spacing....   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"

Comment: Also add a background color to your LinearLayout, so that when you get this screen it will show how much space is covered by an item and then you can add/remove margins and paddings accordingly.

Comment: YOU ARE KIDDING ME!!! OH MY GOSH! I dunno why when I tried that before it didn't give me an option to do that (ctrl+space auto complete help) .... Oh man.. I wasted a day!
Thanks a tonne and sorry for the caps, I'm just totally ... well you know what. :(

Answer (score 0):

`Android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"` this doesn't work, if you have a fixed size in the root element (ex- card) of the item layout that you are setting for the grid

Set the width like this - `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

**Activiy layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.legacy_grid_view.LegacyGridActivity">


    <GridView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/legacyGrid"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_away" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/legacyGridEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Result**

[image]